# JDBC connection does not work properly but sqlplus connection works well

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, spring-jdbc

We have an application where its metadata is in a production database. We connect to the production database via jdbc connection.

When we change the database to a second database (which is the production database's standby located in a different city), either we cannot connect to it, or we connect to it after a long waiting period. Even if we connect to it, our application runs very slowly, then drops connection after a while.

The databases have same versions. By the way when we connect to the standby db via sqlplus, we connect to it very quickly just as the production database.

What could be the problem when connecting via jdbc?

In addition: We upgraded the jdbc drive, nothing has changed

More: We have other applications like abinito, we do not use jdbc there . We connect to the standby and run things very quickly

Solution: I do not know whether it is a bug or not.This configuration has worked properly. jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = myservice)))

```
jdbc
jdbc.driverclass=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myservice
jdbc.username=xxx
jdbc.password=xxx
jdbc.maxPoolSize=300
jdbc.minPoolSize=5
jdbc.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod=1800
jdbc.checkoutTimeout=3000000
~                        

ping status

ping standby_db
icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=7.02 ms
icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=6.89 ms
icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=6.79 ms
^C
ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.790/6.903/7.020/0.093 ms


ping prod_db

icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.450 ms
icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=0.451 ms
icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=0.480 ms

^C
---  ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.450/0.460/0.480/0.022 ms

Here there is the log
    
    2020-06-24 13:30:18,158 ERROR (ContextLoader.java:319) - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduleService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean com.i2i.smartcopy.service.ScheduleService.schedulerFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduleFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5662)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:983)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean com.i2i.smartcopy.service.ScheduleService.schedulerFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduleFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
                    ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduleFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
                    ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
                    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:514)
                    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
                    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:252)
                    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:511)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
                    ... 39 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
                    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
                    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1396)
                    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:473)
                    ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
                    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
                    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
                    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
                    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
                    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
                    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
                    ... 49 more
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you make sure it's not a network connection? You said it's in a different city - ping the two databases, is one connection significantly slower? Also, can you post your JDBC connection string or DataSource configuration, otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Hi, I added more information to my question. The thing that I do not understand is that why I connect to the standby database very slow while I connect to it  via sqlplus very fast. The network team or database admin team indicates that there is no problem. We can connect to every ip via telnet. I really do not understand the problem

Comment: Try to increase logging, e.g. set `log.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG` or even `TRACE` and other log groups maybe as well. Maybe you can find something.

Comment: this configuration has worked. jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = myservice)))

Comment: The problem was found in the database level. DBAs solved the problem by adding the missing parameter